Combine scatter with grouped bar plot using plotly
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5], [10, 30, 20, 60, 30], [3,3,4,5,8],[9, 1,2,3,4], [1,1,2,2,2]], columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], index=["vial1", "vial2", "vial3", "vial4", "vial5"])
asdf = px.bar(df.T, barmode="group")
asdf = asdf.add_scatter(x=["A", "A", "B"], y=[10,20,30], mode="markers", alignmentgroup="vial1")
asdf

I want to combine grouped bar plot with scatter traces, showing individual data for each column. How do I make the scatter traces to go to their respective bars in the group of bars?
In my example, the scatter points are always in the middle above “vial3” but should be above “vial1”.

